# ASP.NET CookieAuthentication does not store cookie longer than browser session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, azure, cookies

I am using ASP.NET MVC 6 and trying to store session cookies, but when I open the browser it just says Expires: Session.

Startup.cs:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = false;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        });
```

This should set the cookie to last 30 days, but that does not work.

Second question, where is the session information stored? I am hosting this using Microsoft Azure and also use SQL storage, but have not set anything up specifically for handling session storage.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application span multiple instances or autoscales? You might need to setup the [DataProtection service](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html) if it does, since one request can be authenticated but the next one (that may land on another instance) will not.

Right now our `Startup.cs` file has the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddDataProtection();
    services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
    {
        configure.SetApplicationName("YourAppName");
    });
    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //...

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/");
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;

        });

        //...
    }
```

That makes sure that cookies get shared across all your WebApp instances.

Comment: Does this also work for Web Roles (rather than WebApps) in Azure?

Comment: For Web Roles I'd try storying the Keys somewhere else, like Azure Storage, check this announcemente: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/